# How to pass a multidimensional double array in Android?

Tags: android, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to pass my double array from one activity to the other. However I cannot figure out how to do this, as the methods I' ve tried just give me error messages.

This is what I' ve tried in my MainActivity:

```
               intent.putExtra("nutritional_value", temp.nutritional_value);
```

(in case necessary: I have defined the variable 'temp' in a third java class like this):

```
SingleItem temp = list.get(position);
```

This is what I' ve tried to do in my second activity:

```
        double[][] nutritional_value = intent.getDoubleArrayExtra("nutritional_value", 0);
```

I' m not exactly new to Android but I' m still in the learning curve, please tell me if you know how I can fix this, I would really appreciatie it.

Thanks

Comment: What kind of error messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try serialzing the array, something along the lines of

```
double[][] nutritional_value =....

Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putSerializable("array_array",  nutritional_value );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't like that. `putExtra` doesn't take multidimentsional . You'll need to either:

Wrap it in a [`Parcelable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) class you will have to write.

Serialize it in some other way. Gson to string for example. Gson will cope with multidimensional arrays.

[`getDoubleArrayExtra`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getDoubleArrayExtra(java.lang.String)) refers to a single dimensional array of `double` values.